# How do I extract table name between from and where using unix from a .txt file

Tags: shell

i have a file like this..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO L_COUNT
    FROM AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS
    WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'CM'
    AND CURRENCY_CODE = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.CURRENCY_CODE
    AND REASON_CODE = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.REASON_CODE
        AND PRIMARY_FLAG = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.PRIMARY_FLAG
    AND ((AMOUNT_FROM BETWEEN :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_FROM AND 
                    :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_TO)
      OR (AMOUNT_TO BETWEEN :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_FROM AND 
                    :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_TO)
      OR ((AMOUNT_FROM <:AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_FROM) AND 
            (AMOUNT_TO >:AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_TO)))
        AND USER_ID != :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.USER_ID;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO L_COUNT
    FROM AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS
    WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'CM'
    AND CURRENCY_CODE = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.CURRENCY_CODE
    AND REASON_CODE = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.REASON_CODE
    AND USER_ID = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.USER_ID;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO L_COUNT
    FROM AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS
    WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'CM'
    AND CURRENCY_CODE = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.CURRENCY_CODE
    AND REASON_CODE = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.REASON_CODE
        AND PRIMARY_FLAG = :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.PRIMARY_FLAG
    AND ((AMOUNT_FROM BETWEEN :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_FROM AND 
                    :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_TO)
      OR (AMOUNT_TO BETWEEN :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_FROM AND 
                    :AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_TO)
      OR ((AMOUNT_FROM <:AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_FROM) AND 
            (AMOUNT_TO >:AR_APPROVAL_USER_LIMITS.AMOUNT_TO))
    );
      DEF_WHERE := ADD_AND( DEF_WHERE ) || '((USER_ID) IN '||'(SELECT
          USER_ID '||'FROM FND_USER WHERE '|| SUB_WHERE || '))';
```

i need to filter the table name between from and where.. please help.. thanks in advance..

Comment: so you want to retrieve all table names that are between `from` and `where`?

Comment: yeah, by using shells script..

Comment: unix.. I have converted a .fmb file in oracle forms to .txt file by using shells f60gen.. now i need to filter the table names which are used in the select statements.. I tried by using sql,plsql am not able to do it..  so i thought it can be done by using shells script.. so is there any commands to filter it..

Comment: Without knowing your OS it's difficult to answer. You can try using `grep -wioP ' *FROM \K.*?(?= WHERE|$)' yourfile.txt`

Comment: OS is UNIX.. that command is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your input stands in `a.txt` file; Here is how to process each word:

```
 cat a.txt | tr -cs 'A-Za-z0-9_' '[\n*]' |  tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

First part keeps only alphanum chars and put each one on a single line; second part makes sure everything is in uppercase for easier processing.

The above will list only words, each on a line:

```
SELECT
COUNT
INTO
L_COUNT
FROM
AR_APROVAL_USER_LIMITS
WHERE
DOCUMENT_TYPE
CM
AND
CURENCY_CODE
AR_APROVAL_USER_LIMITS
CURENCY_CODE
[....]
```

Then we can process this flow with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk): you read each line, and if you find FROM, then you just write the following line:

```
cat a.txt | tr -cs 'A-Za-z_' '[\n*]' |  tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' |\
awk ' { 
    if($0=="FROM") {p="FROM"} 
    else if (p=="FROM") {p="" ; print $0} 
}'
```

With your input, this gives:

```
AR_APROVAL_USER_LIMITS
AR_APROVAL_USER_LIMITS
AR_APROVAL_USER_LIMITS
FND_USER
```

It matches your requirement. But be careful, if there is more than one table between `FROM` and `WHERE`, you miss it; so you should go for:

Which looks for `FROM`, then write until line is `WHERE`

```
cat a.txt | tr -cs 'A-Za-z_' '[\n*]' |  tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' |\
awk ' { 
    if($0=="FROM") {p="FROM"} 
    else if (p=="FROM" && $0!="WHERE") {print $0} 
    else {p=""} 
}'
```

Be careful also, because this doesn't work if there are [sql-join](/questions/tagged/sql-join)s. Now you get the idea, maybe you can look a solution of your own for this case.